Firebase function error, It shows internal server error
exports.check_auth_exists = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    let settingdata = await admin.database().ref('settings').once("value");
    let settings = settingdata.val();
    const allowedOrigins = ['https://' + config.firebaseProjectId + '.web.app', settings.CompanyWebsite];
    const origin = request.headers.origin;
    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    }
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    let data = JSON.parse(request.body.data);
    const userData = await formatUserProfile(request, config, data);
    if(userData.uid){
        admin.database().ref('users/' + userData.uid).set(userData);
    }
    response.send(userData)
});

I am deploying this firebase function but it shows internal server error. I am not expert in base64 I don't know how to handle it please anyone help and check it out`

Help us help you - share the full error
